# Hyperdimensional computing versus gradient boosting and NN on tabular data

Tags: neural-networks, boosting

I've been trying to learn hyperdimensional computing (aka vector symbolic architectures). There's not a lot of resources out there. I've found a few examples, but I can't seem to get very good results in my own experiments. The closest I've found is the recipe example at [Tutorial on Hyperdimensional Computing](https://michielstock.github.io/posts/2022/2022-10-04-HDVtutorial/)

The experiment I'm trying to do is the *Binary Classification with a Bank Churn Dataset* that is being ran on Kaggle right now. It appears to be a simple binary classification problem. I first tried neural nets and got 0.87506. I've used CatBoost to get a score of 0.89176. While those are both decent results, I wanted to see how HDC would work.  Unfortunately my score there is 0.73927. I don't know if that's because HDC sucks at this kind of problem or if I'm just not understanding how to properly encode it.

Here's a description of my HDC algorithm:

Building the model (training):

1. Create seed vectors for each column.
2. Create vectors for each row.

   1. Create vectors for each cell value.

      - True/False seed vectors for binary columns.
      - Seed vector for each category in categorical columns.
      - Continuous columns are split into equal sized bins. Each bin gets a seed vector.
   2. Binding operation between column vector and value vector to give the cell vector.
   3. Bundling operation on all cell vectors to get the row vector.
3. Create vectors for each of the two output classifications (Exited and Not Exited).

   1. Group all row vectors by the value in their Exited column.
   2. For each group, run bundling operation on all vectors to get the vector representing that class.

Querying the model (testing):

1. For each row (aka test case):

   1. Generate row vector (same as step 2 above). This will be the query vector.
   2. Execute cosine similarity between query vector and the two classification vectors from step 3.
   3. Whichever classification vector is closer determines what label the test case gets.
2. Calculate accuracy (# of test cases where correct vector was selected) / # of test cases.

I'm still unsure when to bind and when to bundle. And I'm not sure whether permutation comes into play. I don't think it does in this particular kind of problem.

I've played around with different dimension sizes. 10k seems like a common number, so I was expecting that to be good. It seems like I can use 1k and not see any significant change in accuracy.

Is there something about my algorithm that is glaringly wrong?